# Southern Newfoundland and New Brunswick buildings data

Tags: data

I am looking for GIS data for southern Newfoundland and New Brunswick.

For NFLD: - buildings, property line/polygon, basic contours, topographic items
For NB: - buildings

Let me know of any data sources or websites that may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on a few factors, like what type of accuracy, coverage, and cost you looking at. If you are interested in free, and the accuracy and coverage isn't as important, a good start would be the Canada NTS datasets. These datasets are broken into alpha numeric coding, so you will have to look at your map coverage. Here is a link to the download area: ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/bndt/50k_shp_en/

If accuracy and coverage is more important you may want to look at DMTI Spatial. You will have to pay for it. Here is a link to their page: http://www.dmtispatial.com/Software-And-Data/CanMap.html

Answer (score 0):

As a topographic base, you could use SRTM-Elevation-Data which comes as raster-dataset:

Link:
http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp